# React Router with expressjs and httpd not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, express

I have deployed my React App on expressjs, I have httpd already setup to redirect all request /MyApp to my application on expressjs.

Once the expressjs server is up I am able to access my application as http://localhost:3000/.
I have Routers in my react app which will route me to the login page on the above call.

When I try to access through httpd as http://localhost/MyApp/, I get a blank page, the component doesn't get rendered.

Assuming that react-router is unable to handle /MyApp/.

How can I achieve this?

app.use, app.get with the route "/MyApp" didn't work.

App.tsx

```
             <Router>
                <Route  render={({ location, history }) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                                <Route path="/home" component={LoginSuccess} />
                            </Switch>
                        </Suspense>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
                />
            </Router>
```

Using BrowserRouter

Comment: what route are you hosting express on?

Comment: currently, I have removed all the mappings.

Comment: what is your code currently?

Comment: @ChrisGong I have updated the code.

Comment: you don't have a route for `MyApp`, what component do you expect to be loaded on this route?

Comment: I was hoping that there was to handle that mapping with express to redirect to the mapping of `/`.  Since `MyApp` name could vary from deployment to deployment, I would not like to change my code for each time I have a deployment.